# Parse Push Notifications

Tags: xcode, push, helper, apple-push-notifications, push-notification

I am trying to add push notifications to my Xcode app...

Here is what I'm following https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#push

I am on App Integration.

Comment: Please stop adding join.me links to your questions.